# Powershell Mouse Moving Script on XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, script, powershell

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(500,100)
```

The above code should move the mouse to a specific position (500,100), but using Windows PowerShell 2.0 and Windows XP SP3, it is not working.

I am also trying to use this powershell script, which should move the mouse around randomly.  The cursor isn't moving, but the form of the cursor is.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MrPowerScripts/PowerScripts/master/Fun/MouseShaker.ps1

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "form of the cursor"?  Maybe post a screenshot of what you're seeing?